# How to convert object to datetime Index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have dataframe with colum `date`. The values of the `Date` column is like `Index([2011-01-10], dtype='object')`. I want to convert to DateTime but I am not able to do this. I have tried `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])` but it did not work. Got an error `TypeError: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> is not convertible to datetime`. Can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: I suspect that you have length one indices as the values in your `'Date'` column.  That is what we call... messed up!  Try this `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str[0])`

Comment: Try to pass the date index to a column using df['dateindex'] = df.index and then convert to datetime. Or even better as @Vaishali mention, directly convert using df.index.

Comment: Wait, this is strange. The COLUMN date is an Index?

Comment: Since date is an index, use df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

Comment: OP, if the dup target satisfies your needs, please say so.  Otherwise, I can reopen the question.

Comment: I have used date Index from other dataframe as column as present dataframe. May be this is causing error

Comment: @piRSquared I have tried what you have mentioned but I got the following error `Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

Comment: @Alex_P [edit] your post and past the results of this `df.head().to_dict()` to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=[pd.Index(['2018-01-01'])] * 2))

df

                                    Date
0  Index(['2018-01-01'], dtype='object')
1  Index(['2018-01-01'], dtype='object')
```

---

#### The Error

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)    

TypeError: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> is not convertible to datetime
```

---

#### Solution

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date.str[0])

df

        Date
0 2018-01-01
1 2018-01-01
```